# Como ter uma WebView em tela cheia?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview

Minha dúvida específica: Como abrir uma `WebView` em tela cheia no Android Studio?

Alterar Theme no Manifest? Alterar Theme no XML? Forçar um script JAVA?
Alterar as margens da view? Alterar código no Style?

Todas essas tentativas citadas acima foram testadas exaustivamente, principalmente vinda de sites estrangeiros. Mesmo quando pesquiso conteúdo em inglês, vejo a dificuldade que é encontrar a solução para uma webview em tela cheia. Muitas vezes a suposta solução é ocultar a barra de títulos do aplicativo, sobrando aquela margem no aplicativo, não solucionando o problema específico. Meu projeto está assim:

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.duff.webviewoficial">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/TelaCheia">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.duff.webviewoficial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //aqui a mágica   REMOVE A BARRA DE TITULO
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Aparentemente habilitado

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return false;
         }
        });


        mWebView.loadUrl("http://duffproapps.16mb.com/appFinal/home2.html");
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        //http://duffproapps.16mb.com/appFinal/


    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.duff.webviewoficial.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"




        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TelaCheia" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Já tentou configurar no xml para ela pegar toda tela? você pode fazer isso com facilidade no editor gráfico do Android Studio!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para deixar o `WebView` em [tela cheia](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/fullscreen.html) ou *fullscreen*, no inglês,  primeiramente você deve definir tanto altura quanto largura como `math_parent`. Logo depois basicamente há duas maneiras deixar o dispositivo em preencher todo espaço da tela, via XML e programaticamente. Veja:

### XML:

No `AndroidManifest.xml` do seu projeto:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityMain"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

### Programaticamente:

Na *activity* que você desejar que seja `FULLSCREEN`:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // removendo o título
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Como também especificado na documentação sobre [boas práticas para interface de usuário](https://developer.android.com/training/best-ui.html), existe uma técnica chamada [**Immersive Full-Screen Mode**](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) disponível a partir versão KitKat do Android.

Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber mais detalhes, leia mais [**na documentação**](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

Comment: Post muito bom. Embora não seja o caso. Dei um +1 para quem precisar de algo semelhante, pois o template fica bonito assim, sem a barra de título. O meu também é assim, embora eu tenha conseguido de outra forma. Não consegui o full screen. Como eu tinha dito antes, alterar o theme para "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" nunca funcionou. Desenvolvo em um MacBook Pro. Será que o SDK para Mac OS não tem esse tema?

Comment: Sobre o JAVA, só consigo erro no gradle.

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff comigo sempre funcionou. Você chegou a tentar usando AppCompat? Desta forma: `Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen`

Comment: <style name="TelaCheia" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen" >
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen">Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen</style>

Comment: Ta assim até o momento

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff desse jeito que você me mandou, eu abri aqui e mostra `fullscreen` normalmente, sem nenhum problema.

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff Veja: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfzFAS7MTC0OFk4eW1GdVVhSEk

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff Porém eu comentei essa parte na classe: `//getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);`

Comment: Acabo de comentar a mesma linha também. Estou desconfiado que isso tem alguma coisa haver com a versão da SDK. Está usando Windows, MAC ou Linux?
Olha como ficou:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0iOWJod1WArWE55N1B6WUJUY3M/view?usp=sharing

Existe uma pequena linha do menu em colorido que faz perceber a faixa em branco na tela. Coloquei aquela borda no CSS para ficar mais explícito. Você reproduziu o projeto arquivo por arquivo? Pois quando possível posso tentar a mesma coisa usando um projeto em branco ou no Windows.

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff Aqui estou no Windows. Será que não é problema no seu emulador? Qual versão que está no seu emulador? Tem algum dispositivo ai pra poder testar direto?!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51726/discussion-between-paulo-sergio-duff-and-ack-lay).

Comment: Sue resposta deu jeito. Tive problemas com emulador!

Answer (score 0):

EDITADO:

```
    <FrameLayout             
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Usei o seu proprio "TelaCheia" no Manisfest e funcionou.
Precisei retirar assa parte
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //aqui a mágica   REMOVE A BARRA   DE TITULO
    getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,     Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/TelaCheia"> <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<=========
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Não,  não funciona.

Answer (score -2):

É muito simples gente! Não precisa de nada disso! Uso o sketchware  procurei a mesma coisa e encontrei algo muito prático

Veja como é facil assistir um video de youtube em tela cheia, ou mesmo criar um webview com video em tela cheia.

1 - Abra o google chrome navegador do cel.

2 - entre no youtube normalmente

3 - digite o nome do video desejado

4 - suponhamos que essa seria a url do video -> https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-3C6hX4PTLk

5 - troque o 'm' por 'www' e o 'watch?v=' por 'embed/'

6 - ficaria assim: https://www.youtube.com/embed/-3C6hX4PTLk

7 - copie e cole na barra de endereços, e pronto, video em fullscreen!

Boa Sorte!